# why kubetest does not install according to instructions?

Tags: go, kubernetes

According to the page [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-testing/e2e-tests.md), kubetest should be installed with the following go command:

```
go get -u k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest
```

I've done that and tried running `kubetest` but it appears that it was not installed.

```
$ kubetest
kubetest: command not found
```

Is this not the correct way of installing it? Or is there anything extra that needs to be done? If so, why is it not mentioned in the readme?

---

edit:

here is my go version:

```
$ go version
go version go1.13.4 linux/amd64
```

---

edit:

Here is a partial output from my install command:

```
$ go get -v -u k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest
get "k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"k8s.io/test-infra", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://github.com/kubernetes/test-infra"} at //k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest?go-get=1
get "k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
k8s.io/test-infra (download)
github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go (download)
github.com/Azure/go-autorest (download)
github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go (download)
...
k8s.io/api/settings/v1alpha1
k8s.io/api/storage/v1
k8s.io/api/storage/v1alpha1
k8s.io/api/storage/v1beta1
k8s.io/client-go/tools/reference
k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/scheme
```

Comment: Is your GOPATH's bin directory in your $PATH?

Comment: `go get` should install the binary. What output are you getting from the command? Are you suing the current version of Go?

Comment: I think you're missing some errors in the output there. There's nothing to add here, `go get` should work unless they document some other method for building the project. When in doubt however, figure out how the developers must be building it. go to the `$HOME/go/src/k8s.io/test-infra/kubetest` directory and use `go get` or `go install` from there. Some part of the module structure isn't working correctly.

Comment: I could not find any errors in the output. I pasted the full output on paste bin: https://pastebin.com/WkNwuBc6 if you want to have a look

Comment: However, your suggestion to perform an install from `test-infra/kubetest` seemed to have done the trick. there is not a `bin` directory in `$HOME/go` and it contains `kubetest` as an executable. So thank you for the help!

Comment: I do wonder if I should open that as an issue on the github project, as the documented method of installation did not work, and I might not be the only one...

Comment: Can Anyone let me know whether you found solution for this? am facing the same issue here

Answer (score 2):

`go get` by default places projects in the directory defined as your `$GOPATH`, which by default is `$HOME/go`. Binaries are by default placed in `$GOPATH/bin`. Ensure that `GOPATH/bin` is added to your `$PATH` variable, otherwise you are unable to use binaries fetched using `go get`.

Comment: the GOPATH environment variable is not defined on my system. and the /home/go dir only contains `pkg` and `src` directories. no `bin` directory

Comment: I have found this variable to point to /home/tomk/go. which, as I mentioned, does not contain a `bin` directory